# Hide Keyboard from editText within dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog

I know how to hide keyboard if class is extends Activity, but when it extends DialogFragment my code for hide keyboard from Activity is doesn't work.

this is my code so far:

```
public class PersonalData extends DialogFragment
     LinearLayout activity_personaldata;

//Oncreate:
activity_personaldata = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id._activity_personaldata_);
    activity_personaldata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
        }
    });
```

and my XML is :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/_activity_personaldata_"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

i have make ID in the linearlayout in my XML, and give focusable. but it still dont work.
please help me, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in the `onCreateView()`.   `getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);`

If you want to hide the keyboard when user clicks on outside of your `EditText`, you can implement a `focusListner` for that `EditText`.

```
 youreditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
               InputMethodManager imm =  (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
               imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: sorry, my title in this post is wrong. I want hide keyboard when user click outside edittext. and show again when user click on edittext. I use linearlayout for hide the keyboard. but it dont work at all..